# Django Bootstrap without Auth User

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-admin

I am currently using `bootstrap_admin` to style the admin area of my app, and I want to unregister the auth and site tables so that only the tables for my own app appear.  When I call `admin.site.unregister(Site)` or `admin.site.unregister(Group)` they work correctly, but when I call `admin.site.unregister(User)` it gives the following error on the `/admin/` page:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/
Reverse for 'auth_user_change' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}'
not found.
```

The error is definitely a result from bootstrap - when I uninstall the app from my settings file, everything works correctly.  I think I might need to override some bootstrap template, but I'm not really sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: looks like an update to bootstrap-admin might fix the issue, unless you are using the latest.

Comment: I think I am using the latest, but I'm not sure - was this a bug they said they had fixed?

Comment: yeah.. had come across this bug, and had to update my package

Comment: I'm currently using 0.2.1 - is that an earlier version that does not have this fix?

Comment: I was using django1.4 and 0.14 of bootstrap admin. had to upgrade to the dev version then.

Comment: More specifically, I have two directories in my site-packages area, labeled `bootstrap_admin` and `bootstrap_admin-0.2.1-py2.7.egg-info`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30770/discussion-between-kvass-and-karthikr)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to install a different version of the bootstrapped admin - The one [here](http://www.codingnot.es/bootstrap-your-django-admin-in-3-minutes/) did the trick.